# new to java - understanding bit operations in practical use

Tags: java, android

```
//determines if string contains unique characters

public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)   <--- right here
            return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

All I understand is that << adds extra zeros to the binary number, thus increasing the value. Ex: 2<< 3 = 10 + 000 = 10000 // which is 16  in binary. So my question is, how is that useful here? how is does that help us find unique characters

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm works, because checker becomes a bitmap that tells what characters were met.

I think I will explain with an example. Let's say our string is 'bedb'.
We start with checker = 0.
Then 'b' comes. `val == 1` because `'b' - 'a' == 1`.

(1 << val) as you said is represented as 10 in binary.

`checker | 10` = `00 | 10` = `10`

It means that we met a `b` (there is a 1 in the second place from right) and did not meet an `a`.
Then `e` comes. `val == 4`. `(1 << val)` is `10000` in binary.

`checker | 10000` = `10 | 10000` = `10010`

Good. Now we know we met an `e` and a `b`.

After `d` comes checker is `11010`.

Then `b` comes. `(1 << val)` is `10`. And here `(checker & (1 << val))` is no longer zero.

`11010 & 10` is `10`.
So the method returns false, because it found a character it met before.

Answer (score 1):

1) Each symbol has a position of 1 in the word, for example: a = 1, b = 10, c = 100, d = 1000
2)The checker saves bit position for each symbol presented before (checker |= (1 << val)
3) If the symbol already saved, the bit in the same position is 1, as result: the equation checker & (1 << val) will be greater than zero (PROFIT) and zero if the position is 0 (there was no the same symbol yet)